# Error 500 for some Ajax requests on server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am getting the 500 Error for some Ajax calls (post and get). I am only getting these in my production(ubuntu server) not local (xampp). CSRF token is sent for the request. Does anybody know what I could do?

the request that works:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:getHerstellerUri,
        success:function(data){ 
            $.each(data,function(j,value){
                var option =$("<option>",
                            {text : value.hersteller})
                $('#hersteller1').append(option);    
            })
    })
```

and here the one that does not work:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url:readHerstellerUri,
                dataType: "json",
                data:{'title':herstellerAuswahl},
                success:function(data){
....
```

my web.php for these ajax calls is:

```
Route::get('/getHersteller', 'HerstellerController@getHersteller')->name('getHersteller');


Route::post('/readHersteller', 'BikeController@readHersteller')->name('readHersteller');
```

and the .htaccess which differs from the local one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle http -> https redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs and Laravel logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of my controller(laravel). Some routes did not work with all controllers. I have no idea why, but if a put the function of the request to another controller it works.

Answer (score 0):

500 status code is server error. so correct your server-side script